# How to create a nameless Json array with Jackson

Tags: json, jackson

The following JSON is required:

```
{[{"value":"1"}, {"value":"2"}, {"value":"3"}, {"value":"4"value}]}
```

Using:

```
    JsonGenerator generator = factory.createGenerator(os, JsonEncoding.UTF8);) {
    generator.writeStartObject();
    generator.writeFieldName("data");
    generator.writeStartArray();
    while (rs.next()) {
        generator.writeStartObject();
        generator.writeStringField("value", rs.getString("value"));
        generator.writeEndObject();
    }
    generator.writeEndArray(); 
    generator.writeEndObject();
    generator.close();
```

outputs:

```
{"data":[{"value":"1"}, {"value":"2"}, {"value":"3"}, {"value":"4"value}]}
```

I don't want the *data* label, but if

```
generator.writeFieldName("data");
```

is removed, the following error is thrown:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Can not start an array, expecting field name (context: Object)
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you might want to just omit the root object declaration and leave it as an array, as it not a valid json format.

```
JsonGenerator generator = factory.createGenerator(os, JsonEncoding.UTF8);
generator.writeStartArray();
while (rs.next()) {
    generator.writeStartObject();
    generator.writeStringField("value", rs.getString("value"));
    generator.writeEndObject();
}
generator.writeEndArray(); 
generator.close();
```

this would return valid `json` format being:

```
[{"value":"1"}, {"value":"2"}, {"value":"3"}, {"value":"4"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @krzysztof-krzeszewski is better and gives the desired result.

Firstly your json example includes a "value" outside any quotes but I am guessing that is a typo.
The problem is that:

```
{[{"value":"1"}, {"value":"2"}, {"value":"3"}, {"value":"4"}]}
```

Is simply not valid json.
You have to add an attribute name to the array because until it has a name it is not valid.
Here is the example you included as valid json with typo fixed.

```
{"data":[{"value":"1"}, {"value":"2"}, {"value":"3"}, {"value":"4"}]}
```